# position an imageView made on the storyboard within the viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have created a `UIImageView` called `spinnerView`, and display it on the story board (second view controller). When a button is pressed, this new view controller is shown, but despite my efforts the image just sits at the top right of the screen. I know i must do something in the `viewDidLoad` to centre the image in the middle of the screen.
Code within the `viewDidLoad`:

```
spinnerView.center= self.view.center;
```

Comment: set frame of the spinner using CGRect..Check whether It is changing as per CGRect or not..R u taken UIImageView at IB or Dynamic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Autolayout -First position the Imageview to the center of your VC in storyboard by dragging it. Create 2 constraints for the ImageView(after selecting the imageview) --> Height and Width and check if they point to being =(equal) to the values mention ie the width and height of the imageview.

Now select the imageview and Editor-->Align Vertical centre and again repeat for Align Horizontal centre.  This is make sure that the imageview will always be horizontally and vertically at the centre of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set constraints for your imageview in storyboard..